# GradientDrawable.setColors in RecyclerView not working properly

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, drawable

I have a `RecyclerView` that contains a `CircularImageView` (`ImageView` successor) for each element. So far, I set the `src` of the `ImageView` to be a predefined drawable shape (had to do that to make the `CircularImageView` work properly), and I just changed the color programmatically, taken from an array of `@ColorRes`.

This is the drawable `shape_colored_circle.xml` (was a solid, not a gradient):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:endColor="#aaa"
        android:centerColor="#aaa"
        android:startColor="#555"
        android:type="linear" />
    <size
        android:height="70dp"
        android:width="70dp" />
</shape>
```

This is the `CircularImageView` (removed irrelevant data):

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/mini_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/shape_colored_circle"/>
```

This is how I change colors in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
int[] colors = activity.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors_palette);
int[] lightColors = activity.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.light_colors_palette);
if (position < colors.length) {
    GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) holder.thumbnail.getDrawable();
    if (gd != null) {
        gd.setOrientation(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR);
        //gd.setColors(new int[] {lightColors[position], lightColors[position], colors[position]});
        gd.setColor(colors[position]);
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: getColor]

The code above is working as expected. Now I want to make the drawable an actual gradient rather than a solid color, but when replacing `setColor` with `setColors`, all elements are colored with the colors that matches the last id (if I have 3 elements and the third color is green, all drawables become green):

[image: getColors]

It's exactly the same as `SetColor` except sending an array of colors rather than a single color, so I have no idea what's the problem here.

Comment: try to `mutate` your drawable before setting the color

Comment: @pskink Thank you sir, problem solved. Still no idea why `setColor` is working properly without mutating.

Comment: see http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/

Comment: it doesn't work properly without else caee. `if (position < colors.length) { color = X;} else { color = Y} `